# What is the right prototype for my SQL code?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am new in learning SQL and I am trying to apply a trig on those two tables by using SQLcl:

```
prodc
```

*( PRODC_NAME, DISCOUNTED    CHAR(1)     DEFAULT 'N',*
    PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODC_NAME));

```
peopleOrder
(  ORDERID, PRODC_NAME,
   PRIMARY KEY (ORDERID, PRODC_NAME),
   FOREIGN KEY (PRODC_NAME) REFERENCES PRODC (PRODC_NAME));
```

I want my trig to do the following:

when I update or insert rows to `peopleOrder`, the trig should check if a row's `product_name` has value 'N' in the discounted column that is located in the `product` table; if it has no 'N' value, it should show an error message.

I tried many ways and the following trig, but when I insert rows, the trig seems to not be working and have no effect on the rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER constraint_1
After UPDATE OR INSERT on peopleOrder 
for each row
begin
    if not (:new.prodc_name in 
    (select prodc_name from prodc where discounted = 'N' )) then
     RAISE_ERROR(-30001, 'No product can be ordered 
 !');
    END IF; 
    INSERT INTO peopleOrder  VALUES (:new.ORDERID, :new.PRODC_NAME);
END; 
/
```

My insert command is:

```
INSERT INTO peopleOder (ORDERID, PRODC_NAME) 
VALUES (251, 'Puton');
```

*and 'Puton' has value 'N' in the discounted column in the prodc table.*

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Oracle, or something else?

Comment: plsql and mysql   triggers are not constructed in the same way what DB server are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracel SQLcl

Comment: I replaced the [tag:mysql] tag with [tag:oracle].

Comment: based on your trigger you should get mutating error and also is the insert into table peopleOder or peopleOrder

Comment: There is no spelling mistakes in my code, but I have no idea about the right prototype of doing this trigger by a right way

Comment: I know taht the right way to get this question done is by ignoring my trigger and considering the requirement with the tables.

Comment: Simply, if I inserted a row to peopleOrder table, this row should be check whether its product name has value 'N' in the product table. Remember that there is a foreign key in the peopleOredr table linked to the product table.

Comment: The foreign key won't be violated as I will insert values that available in the other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need is to understand what a trigger is. It is a piece of code that runs **as part of** the statement causing it to fire. For this reason you *cannot* reference the table causing it to fire. Normally that is completely unnecessary anyway. Every row trigger has access to to 2 rows: a copy of the existing data (old) and the resulting data (new). Update having both filled and Insert/Delete just new/old as appropriate for the action. Before statement triggers can modify the new data, after triggers cannot. Those rows allow you to process the columns in the table without DML or select on it. (However you cannot 'scan' the table). At any level a trigger may raise an exception which halts the entire process and the invoking statement. If no exception is raised then processing the invoking proceeds. For a more complete description see [PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020) or the version of Oracle you are running.  
In this case your trigger breaks down to a single if 
statement.

```
-- Revised. Orig missed that flag comming from different table.

    create or replace trigger constraint_1
    before update or insert on peopleOrder 
    for each row
    declare 
        dis_num integer; 
    begin  
        select count(*)
          into dis_num
          from product 
         where discounted != 'N'
           and product_name = :new.product_name
           and rownum < 2; 
        if dis_num != 0 then 
           raise_application_error(-20001, 'No discounted product can be ordered!');
        end if; 
    end constraint_1;



-- Orig ==============================================
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER constraint_1
    before UPDATE OR INSERT on peopleOrder 
    for each row
    begin
        if :new.discounted = 'N' then
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'No discounted product can be ordered')
        end if; 
    END; 
    /
```

Comment: But here, discounted is part of the product table not the peopleOrder table because I need to insert values to the peopleOrder. I think the if statement should be "if :new.product_name" and there should be a code follows this if statement which checks if this product_name is discounted in the product table.

Comment: But here, discounted is part of the product table not the peopleOrder table because I need to insert values to the peopleOrder. I think the if statement should be "if :new.product_name" and there should be a code follows this if statement which checks if this product_name is discounted in the product table. For example, consider this insert command (insert into peopleOrder values (251, 'Cocky')), if Cocky  is discounted in the product table then let's it in, if it is not discounted, then show the error message that tells me this product it is not discounted in the product table.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Your IF should be ok as it stands. If that functions correctly just remove the insert statement. Basically that says if the condition is not met the raise an error, If it is met then continue processing. The thing is do not attempt to insert into the table, the trigger is part of that very thing.

Comment: I got this when I implemented it  without the insertion command.                                                                      
                                       LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
2/5       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
3/5       PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: And when I inserted a row, I got this Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'CONSTRAINT1' is invalid and failed
re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

Comment: Since the error you are now reporting is a compile time error it means your trigger never compiles. That is why it never seemed to run. It has nothing to do with the presence/absence of the following insert. That would have generated a  mutating error as mentioned by  @psaraj12. Any I've update my answer to a trigger that functions.